# How do I scroll a TScrollbar using the mouse wheel?

Tags: delphi, scrollbar, message

I have a TScrollBar having a code in the OnScroll event.

I want to scroll it using the mouse wheel, but turning the mouse wheel does not scroll the scroll bar and does not trigger the OnScroll event.

Any idea?

Comment: Considering your rep, you should know by now that most of us can't do much without you showing us your code and telling us what you have tried and how it didn't work (what did you expect and what actually happened).

Comment: A wider question occurs to me reading this. I've been doing a mod that intercepts the mouse wheel message to get TListBox etc 'working correctly'. I'm still doing this in XE. Is this right? Why is there not yet 'correct' behavious out of the box with XE? Is this for legacy reasons?

Comment: Sad. So many people rushed to criticize the question; none of those rushed to answer. Conclusion: on SO is so easy to criticize, especially when you don't have an answer.

Answer (score 24):

```
procedure TForm1.FormMouseWheel(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState;
  WheelDelta: Integer; MousePos: TPoint; var Handled: Boolean);
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  Handled := PtInRect(ScrollBox1.ClientRect, ScrollBox1.ScreenToClient(MousePos));
  if Handled then
    for I := 1 to Mouse.WheelScrollLines do
    try
      if WheelDelta > 0 then
        ScrollBox1.Perform(WM_VSCROLL, SB_LINEUP, 0)
      else
        ScrollBox1.Perform(WM_VSCROLL, SB_LINEDOWN, 0);
    finally
      ScrollBox1.Perform(WM_VSCROLL, SB_ENDSCROLL, 0);
    end;
end;
```

Comment: -1 It's about a ScrollBar, not a ScrollBox. Besides, perform works only for/on VCL internals.

Answer (score 4):

The default TScrollBar component indeed seems not to have the OnMouseWheel* events present. But you can simply assign them, as follows:

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ScrollBar1: TScrollBar;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure ScrollBar1Scroll(Sender: TObject; ScrollCode: TScrollCode;
      var ScrollPos: Integer);
  private
    procedure ScrollBarMouseWheel(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState;
      WheelDelta: Integer; MousePos: TPoint; var Handled: Boolean);
  end;

...

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ScrollBar1.OnMouseWheel := ScrollBarMouseWheel;
end;

procedure TForm1.ScrollBarMouseWheel(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState;
  WheelDelta: Integer; MousePos: TPoint; var Handled: Boolean);
var
  NewScrollPos: Integer;
begin
  NewScrollPos := ScrollBar1.Position - WheelDelta;
  //Trigger the OnScroll event:
  ScrollBar1.Scroll(scPosition, NewScrollPos);
  //Scroll the bar into the new position:
  ScrollBar1.Position := NewScrollPos;
  Handled := True;
end;
```

You are free to implement this some more creative:

```
  if WheelDelta > 0 then
    NewScrollPos := ScrollBar1.Position - ScrollBar1.PageSize
  else
    NewScrollPos := ScrollBar1.Position + ScrollBar1.PageSize;
```

And you could interpose the TScrollBar class to prevent to assign the event at runtime:

```
type
  TScrollBar = class(StdCtrls.TScrollBar)
  protected
    function DoMouseWheel(Shift: TShiftState; WheelDelta: Integer;
      MousePos: TPoint): Boolean; override;
  end;

function TScrollBar.DoMouseWheel(Shift: TShiftState; WheelDelta: Integer;
  MousePos: TPoint): Boolean;
var
  NewScrollPos: Integer;
begin
  NewScrollPos := Position - WheelDelta;
  Scroll(scPosition, NewScrollPos);
  Position := NewScrollPos;
  Result := True;
end;
```

Comment: Answer is missing ScrollBarMouseWheel procedure

Answer (score 3):

it's too easy just increase the position Value .

```
procedure TForm1.FormMouseWheel(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState;
WheelDelta: Integer; MousePos: TPoint; var Handled: Boolean);
begin
self.VertScrollBar.Position :=  self.VertScrollBar.Position + WheelDelta;
end;
```

Comment: This worked for me just had to change the + to a - else it goes backwards "inverted scroll" LOL

Comment: The question is about a ScrollBar, not about a Form, nor any other TScrollingWinControl.

Comment: This answer works if you replace the TScrollBox reference 'self.VertScrollBar' with the name of your TScrollBar.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will help much, but here's how to do it with a TMemo.  The scrollbar would have to be a similar process, unless there is some other better way that Delphi versions later than mine use.

```
procedure TForm1.Memo1WindowProc(var msg: TMessage);
  var
    ticks: ShortInt;
    ScrollMsg: TWMVScroll;
  begin
    if msg.Msg = WM_MOUSEWHEEL then
      begin
        ScrollMsg.Msg := WM_VSCROLL;
        ticks := HiWord(msg.wparam);
        if ticks > 0 then
          ScrollMsg.ScrollCode := sb_LineUp
        else
          ScrollMsg.ScrollCode := sb_LineDown;
        ScrollMsg.Pos:=0;
        Memo1.Dispatch(ScrollMsg) ;
      end
    else
      OldMemo1(msg);
    end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
 // save old window proc, assign mine.
  begin
    OldMemo1 := Memo1.WindowProc;
    Memo1.WindowProc := Memo1WindowProc;
  end;
```

HTH some.

Answer (score 0):

```
procedure TForm1.FormMouseWheelDown(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState;
  MousePos: TPoint; var Handled: Boolean);
begin
  ScrollBox1.VertScrollBar.Position := ScrollBox1.VertScrollBar.Position + 20;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormMouseWheelUp(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState;
  MousePos: TPoint; var Handled: Boolean);
begin
  ScrollBox1.VertScrollBar.Position := ScrollBox1.VertScrollBar.Position - 20;
end;
```

Comment: You should read about formatting code and fix Your answer. It would be much easier to read. http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: The question is about a ScrollBar, not a ScrollBox.

Answer (score 0):

Old post, but I found solution. Simply do

```
procedure TForm1.FormMouseWheel(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState;
  WheelDelta: Integer; MousePos: TPoint; var Handled: Boolean);
begin
  inherited;

  ScrollBox1.ScrollBy(WheelDelta, 0);
end;
```

Works for me.

Comment: The question is about a ScrollBar, not a ScrollBox.

Comment: Besides the fact that it's about ScrollBar, using ScrollBy scrolls the complete control including the scroll bar itself and scrolls it horizontally. Much better results are achieved by using "ScrollBox1.VertScrollBar.Position := ScrollBox1.VertScrollBar.Position - WheelDelta;". Also Handled should be set to true.

Answer (score -1):

Again this is an old post, and it got me most of the way to what i wanted but a little further tweak to the answer by Stefan, restricting scrolling to when the mouse is over the scrollbar.  This detects that the mouse is over the scrollbar (non-client area) of the scroll box before accepting the mousewheel input./  I need this because my scollbox contained comboboxes which users wanted to be able to scrool with the wheel, as well as scrolling the scrollbox (or whatever control is using a scrollbar):

```
  Handled := PtInRect(scrollbox.BoundsRect, scrollbox.ScreenToClient(MousePos)) 
             and not PtInRect(scrollbox.ClientRect, scrollbox.ScreenToClient(MousePos));
  if Handled then
    for I := 1 to Mouse.WheelScrollLines do
    try
      if WheelDelta > 0 then
        scrollbox.Perform(WM_VSCROLL, SB_LINEUP, 0)
      else
        scrollbox.Perform(WM_VSCROLL, SB_LINEDOWN, 0);
    finally
      scrollbox.Perform(WM_VSCROLL, SB_ENDSCROLL, 0);
    end;
```

Comment: The question is about a ScrollBar, not about a ScrollBox, nor any other TScrollingWinControl.